# Listview with horizontal orientation can be split in rows?

Tags: listview, javafx

Can a listview with horizontal orientation be split in rows after set of item for example we have 20 items and to show them in 2 rows with 10 items each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the use of ListView unecessary here. Even if you manage to do that with ListView there is an easier way, just use a **TilePane** , at least that's how I would do it :

```
TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
tilePane.setVgap(3);
tilePane.setHgap(3);
tilePane.setPrefColumns(10);
```

This will align the items into rows. Don't forget to specify the prefColumns to your desire. After that you need to manage the selection on Nodes inside by yourself.

Full example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TilePaneExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private TilePane tilePane;
    private Label selectedLabel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        String items[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };

        tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white ;");
        tilePane.setVgap(10);
        tilePane.setHgap(10);
        tilePane.setPrefColumns(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            addTileNode(items[i]);
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tilePane));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addTileNode(String text) {
        Label l = new Label(text);
        l.setPrefSize(100, 50);
        // l.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("your image")));
        l.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (selectedLabel != l) {
                clearSelection();
                selectLabel(l);
                doSomething();
            } else {
                clearSelection();
            }
        });
        tilePane.getChildren().add(l);
    }

    private void selectLabel(Label label) {
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #AFEEEE ;");
        selectedLabel = label;
    }

    private void clearSelection() {
        if (selectedLabel != null)
            selectedLabel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white ;");
    }

    private void doSomething() {}
}
```

If you really want to stick with ListView the only possible way I can think of is to put the first 10 Nodes into the first Row wrapped inside a HBox ( or something similar ) and do the same for the rest of your nodes for the second row.

P.S. It could not be a beautiful solution with ListView

**Requested Code :**

The above implementation with multiple selections while holding the Ctrl Key down

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TilePaneExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private TilePane tilePane;
    private ArrayList<Label> allSelectedLabels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        String items[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };

        tilePane = new TilePane();
        tilePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white ;");
        tilePane.setVgap(10);
        tilePane.setHgap(10);
        tilePane.setPrefColumns(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            addTileNode(items[i]);
        }

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tilePane));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addTileNode(String text) {
        Label l = new Label(text);
        l.setPrefSize(100, 50);

        l.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (!allSelectedLabels.contains(l)) {
                if (!e.isControlDown()) {
                    clearSelection();
                }
                selectLabel(l);
                doSomething();
            } else {
                if (e.isControlDown()) {
                    clearSelection(l);
                } else {
                    clearSelection();
                }
            }
        });
        tilePane.getChildren().add(l);
    }

    private void clearSelection(Label label) {
        if (label != null){
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white ;");
            allSelectedLabels.remove(label);
        }
    }

    private void selectLabel(Label label) {
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #AFEEEE ;");
        allSelectedLabels.add(label);
    }

    private void clearSelection() {

        for (Label l : allSelectedLabels) {
            l.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white ;");
        }

        allSelectedLabels.clear();

    }

    private void doSomething() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JKostikiadis it was very helpful. And i need to have multi-select items is that possible in this way?

Comment: Of course. You just need to have a list with the selected Labels instead of just one selectedLabel for example ArrayList<Label> allSelectedLabels. To make a multi selection i would check if the shift key is down ( pressed ) inside the mouseClicked Listener and if so i will add the label to the selectedLabelList ( which you should have defined ) and select it as well. If the shift is not down then you need to modify the clearSelection to remove the style from all the labels inside the ArrayList I will update by code in a few

Comment: Depends on how many items. A TilePane gets really slow if you put thousands of items in it, while a ListView remains fast.